# MKMapView setCenterCoordinate: not centering coordinate in view

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm attempting to center a MKMapView on the coordinate of an annotation upon selection with 
`mapView.setCenterCoordinate(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)`.

However the map is instead (and consistently) placing the annotation about 100px vertically off center.
[image]

In 
`mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)` I'm doing some debug logging to illustrate the problem.

> `The coordinate I'm attempting to center on.`
>   set center coordinate to CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7197525, longitude: -73.9896055)
>
> `The map's bounds (this is the expected value).`
>   (lldb) po mapView.bounds
>   (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 375, height = 503))
>
> `The map's center (this is the expected value, i.e. the map isn't bigger than expected).`
>   (lldb) po mapView.bounds.center
>   (x = 187.5, y = 251.5)
>
> `The maps center coordinate (also expected).`
>   (lldb) po mapView.centerCoordinate
>   (latitude = 40.719752499999998, longitude = -73.98960550000001)
>
> `Ask the map to convert it's center coordinate to view points (NOT the expected value).`
>  
>   (lldb) po mapView.convertCoordinate(mapView.centerCoordinate, toPointToView: mapView)
>   (x = 187.5, y = 358.49999999998431)
>
> `Ask the map to convert it's bounds center to map coordinates (this matches what is displayed).`
>  
>   (lldb) po mapView.convertPoint(mapView.bounds.center, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
>   (latitude = 40.747910796601502, longitude = -73.98960550000001)

What I expect to happen is that after calling `setCenterCoordinate:` (and the animation completed) that the supplied coordinate is roughly at the center of the `MKMapView`. Conversely I'd expect that converting the `centerCoordinate` of point of the map to view coordinates `convertCoordinate` would roughly match the value from `mapView.bounds.center`. Any insight into where this extra offset is coming from would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: any progress? I have the same problem :-(